# How do I get each ending in Maldita Castilla?

Tags: maldita-castilla

According to the [download page](http://www.locomalito.com/maldita_castilla.php),
"4 different endings based on merits and secrets".

Comment: Is this actually for an achievement, or was that a placeholder tag?

Comment: It's a placeholder tag. There was no maldita-castilla and I needed a tag to ask the question. (I don't have enough rep to create tags.)

Comment: @hwiechers you can ask on the chat for help when this occurs. or post a comment.

Comment: @Michel Can you add that as an instruction to the 'Ask a Question' page? Because how else is someone supposed to know?

Comment: @hwiechers `"If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)"` There is an instruction on the FAQ for this already =)

Comment: It's not so clear, but... sometimes a subjective question is good, other times they are not. You post your question then we evaluate it. As you can evaluate the other questions as well. Go to the chat when you need extra info. Some times, I go to the chat THEN I open my question. this help me to get more info, so I can build a better question that'll probably help me solve my problem asap.

Answer (score 1):

The 4 endings can be achieved like this:

- Finish the game without collecting all 5 Moura tears
- Finish the game with all the tears but using more than 4 continues
- Finish the game with all the tears and using less than 4 continues
- Finish the game as above but completing 7 legendary tasks as well.